# Inserting the whole VBA Code, which includes multiple Do Loops in a For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

My code currently asks for the product code and the quantity of the product, and displays the total cost and the discount the consumer gets. However, I now need to use a For Loop that asks the "different types of products bought," and thus, place my current code in this For LOOP. That is, each time through the loop you should get and display information about a particular product purchased. I have spent hours trying to insert my code in a For Loop to no avail. Any help would be immensely useful since I am rather inexperienced and teaching myself! thanks!

```
Sub Product() 
Dim ProductCode  As String 
Dim ErrorCheck As Boolean 
Dim Cost As Double, MinQty As Double, Discount As Double 
Dim MyRange As Range 
Dim found As Variant 
Dim QtyBought As Integer 
Dim TotalCost As Double 

Set MyRange = Worksheets("Data").Cells '<-- the range containing the data provided


Do '"main" outer loop
    Do '"Product code input" inner loop
        ProductCode = Application.InputBox("Enter the Product's code.", Type:=2) '<--| force string input
    Loop While ProductCode = "" 


    found = Application.Match(ProductCode, MyRange.Columns(1), 0) '<-- try getting ow index of prodcut code in 1st column of "MyRange" range
    If IsError(found) Then '<--| if no match found...
        MsgBox "The value entered was not found!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please, try again", vbCritical + vbOKOnly '<-- inform the user and loop again
    Else '<--| otherwise
        With MyRange(found, 1) '<-- reference the matching cell
            Cost = .Offset(0, 1).Value '<--| store "Cost from cell 1 column to the right of the referenced one
            MinQty = .Offset(0, 2).Value '<--| store "MinQty" from cell 2 columns to the right of the referenced one
            Discount = .Offset(0, 3).Value '<--| store "Discount" from cell 3 columns to the right of the referenced one
        End With 
    End If 
Loop While IsError(found) 

 'Obtaining QtyBought Value
QtyBought = InputBox("Enter the QtyBought ordered.") 


 'Error checking
Do Until ErrorCheck = False 
    If IsNumeric(QtyBought) = False Then 
        ErrorCheck = True 
        MsgBox ("Not a valid entry.") 
        QtyBought = InputBox("Enter the QtyBought ordered.") 
    Else 
        ErrorCheck = False 
    End If 
Loop 
 'finding out the cost of the prodcut ordered.

TotalCost = Selection.Value * QtyBought 
Discount = Selection.Value * Discount 
 'Obtaining discount rate
If QtyBought > MinQty Then 
    MsgBox ("You purchased " & QtyBought & "units of product " & ProductCode & ".The total cost is " & Format(TotalCost, "$#,##0") & "Because you purchased at least " & MinQty & "units, you get a discount of " & Discount & "on each unit") 

Else 
    MsgBox ("Sorry, You don't qualify for any discount") 

End If 


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have an "outer" Sub calling an "inner" Sub while in a `ProductName` input loop, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Products()
    Dim ProductCode  As String
    Do '"main" outer loop
        Do '"Product code input" inner loop
            ProductCode = Application.InputBox("Enter the ProductCode's code [input space to end]", Type:=2) '<--| force string input
        Loop While ProductCode = ""
        If ProductCode <> " " Then Product ProductCode
    Loop While ProductCode <> " "
End Sub

Sub Product(ProductCode As String)
    Dim Cost As Double, MinQty As Double, Discount As Double
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim found As Variant
    Dim QtyBought As Integer
    Dim TotalCost As Double

    Set MyRange = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange '<-- the range containing the data provided

    found = Application.Match(ProductCode, MyRange.Columns(1), 0) '<-- try getting ow index of prodcut code in 1st column of "MyRange" range
    If IsError(found) Then '<--| if no match found...
        MsgBox "The value entered was not found!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please, try again", vbCritical + vbOKOnly '<-- inform the user and loop again
        Exit Sub '<--| exit sub to get another product code
    End If

    With MyRange(found, 1) '<-- reference the matching cell
        Cost = .Offset(0, 1).Value '<--| store "Cost from cell 1 column to the right of the referenced one
        MinQty = .Offset(0, 2).Value '<--| store "MinQty" from cell 2 columns to the right of the referenced one
        Discount = .Offset(0, 3).Value '<--| store "Discount" from cell 3 columns to the right of the referenced one
    End With

     'Obtaining QtyBought Value
    QtyBought = Application.InputBox("Enter the QtyBought ordered.", Type:=1) '<--| force numeric input

     'finding out the cost of the product ordered.
    TotalCost = Selection.Value * QtyBought '<--shouldn't this be: TotalCost = Cost * QtyBought
    Discount = Selection.Value * Discount '<--shouldn't this be: Discount = TotalCost * Discount
     'Obtaining discount rate
    If QtyBought > MinQty Then
        MsgBox ("You purchased " & QtyBought & "units of product " & ProductCode & ".The total cost is " & Format(TotalCost, "$#,##0") & "Because you purchased at least " & MinQty & "units, you get a discount of " & Discount & "on each unit")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Sorry, You don't qualify for any discount")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou so much again! but could i just ask if it'd be possible to include the original code, in a FOR loop to achieve the same thing?